# Filter inside a subagregation on elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm try to extract aggregated data, but I'm a little lost when I want to further filter a set of documents. Getting the color seems ok, but when I want to aggregate the categories with some colors filter the query fail. What am I doing wrong on this query?

This is the query I already have:

```
GET/my_index/_search
{
  "_source": false,
  "aggs": {
    "global": {
      "global": {

      },
      "aggs": {
        "all_products": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "simple"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "filter_top": {
              "filter": {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "match": {
                        "simple.compound_words": {
                          "query": "tisch",
                          "operator": "AND"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              "aggs": {
                "filter_merged": {
                  "aggs": {
                    "filter": {
                      "bool": {
                        "must": [
                          {
                            "terms": {
                              "simple.filter_color": [
                                "green",
                                "red"
                              ]
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    },
                    "aggs": {
                      "filter_category": {
                        "terms": {
                          "field": "simple.filter_category"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                },
                "filter_color": {
                  "terms": {
                    "field": "simple.filter_color"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is the relevant part of the index mappings.

```
{
  "my_index": {
    "mappings": {
      "_doc": {
        "properties": {
          "simple": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "compound_words": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "GermanCompoundWordsAnalyzer"
              },
              "filter_category": {
                "type": "keyword"
              },
              "filter_color": {
                "type": "keyword"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks for your support.

Comment: Which version of elastic you are using? If 7.x filter is not supported

Comment: The version is 6.4

Comment: Can you add a sample doc so that it would be easy to understand and replicate the problem?

Comment: I added the relevant part of the schema.